# Using Nonces for AJAX that only retrieves data

Tags: ajax, nonce

Does it make sense to use a nonce on an AJAX action that only returns data and doesn't alter data on the server side?  I understand they are important if you are saving data or changing something on the server but if you are just receiving data like a post or metadata, is a nonce really needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not needed. If you want to show the data to some users only, you can use `current_user_can( 'some_capability' )` to restrict the access.